# Import CSV into google cloud datastore

Tags: csv, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a CSV file with 2 columns and 20,000 rows I would like to import into Google Cloud Datastore. I'm new to the Google Cloud and NoSQL databases. I have tried using dataflow but need to provide a Javascript UDF function name. Does anyone have an example of this? I will be querying this data once it's in the datastore.
Any advice or guidance on how to create this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Apache Beam, you can read a CSV file using the `TextIO` class. See the [TextIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html) documentation.

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://path/to/file.csv"));
```

Next, apply a transform that will parse each row in the CSV file and return an `Entity` object. Depending on how you want to store each row, construct the appropriate `Entity` object. [This page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) has an example of how to create an `Entity` object.

```java
.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Entity>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        String row = c.element();
        // TODO: parse row (split) and construct Entity object
        Entity entity = ...
        c.output(entity);
    }
}));
```

Lastly, write the `Entity` objects to Cloud Datastore. See the [DatastoreIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore/DatastoreV1.html) documentation.

```java
.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(projectId));
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I have a coupeIe noob questions. I have taken a look at the TextIO documentation and have a question. Where will I be running TextIO? In Apache Beam or in Dataflow? Also, where will I be applying the transform and writing the entities to Cloud Datastore? I see that I can run jobs in Dataflow. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Apache Beam is a programming model for defining pipelines. The pipelines can be run on an execution engine such as Cloud Dataflow. You don't actually "run" `TextIO`. You define a pipeline using the Apache Beam SDKs. For example, using the Java SDK, `TextIO.Read` is the input transform and `DatastoreV1.Read` is the output transform. You can apply any transform in between to implement ETL logic. Once the pipeline is defined/implemented, it can then be deployed/run.

Answer (score 2):

Simple in python, but can easily adapt to other langauges.  Use the `split()` method to loop through the lines and comma-separated values:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from my.models import MyModel

csv_string   = 'http://someplace.com/myFile.csv'
csv_response = urlfetch.fetch(csv_string, allow_truncated=True) 

if csv_response.status_code == 200:
    for row in csv_response.content.split('\n'):
        row_values = row.split(',')
        # csv values are strings.  Cast them if they need to be something else
        new_entry = MyModel(
            property1 = row_values[0],
            property2 = row_values[1]
        )
        new_entry.put()

else:
    print 'cannot load file: {}'.format(csv_string)
```