# Google Cloud Datastore: Bulk Importing w Node.js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm need to write a huge quantity of entities (1.5 million lines from a .csv file) to Google Cloud Datastore. Kind of a 2 part question:

Can I do (or is `kind` a necessary property?):

```
const item = {
    family: "chevrolet",
    series: "impala",
    data: {
        sku: "chev-impala",
        description: "Chevrolet Impala Sedan",
        price: "20000"
    }
}
```

then, regarding [importing](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) I'm unsure of how this works. If I can't simply dump/upload/import a huge `.json` file, I wanted to use Node.js. I would like each entity to have an autogenerated universal id. Is there an asynchronous means of writing? I have a node script that is piping out a few hundred enteties/records at a time and pausing awaiting write `resolve`. ...which is what I'm looking for : a promise import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache Beam to import data from a CSV file to Cloud Datastore. Take a look in to the thread: [Import CSV into google cloud datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473024/import-csv-into-google-cloud-datastore).

How to work with entities is explained in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities).

[Exporting and Importing Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) is a fully managed service and you can import just entities previously exported with the managed export and import service.