# Property [project] is marked with contradictory annotations

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

My requirement is to read from a csv file in Google Cloud Storage and load it to Google Datastore. Below is the code snippet.

```
import com.google.datastore.v1.Entity;
import com.google.datastore.v1.Key;
import com.opencsv.CSVParser;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.datastore.DatastoreIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.UUID;

import static com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreHelper.makeKey;
import static 
com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreHelper.makeValue;


public class PipelineClass {


static class CreateEntitiesFn extends DoFn<String, Entity> {
  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PipelineClass.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String namespace;
  private final String kind;
  private final Key ancestorKey;

  CreateEntitiesFn(String namespace, String kind) {
      this.namespace = namespace;
      this.kind = kind;


      ancestorKey = makeAncestorKey(namespace, kind);
  }

  Entity makeEntity(String id, String group) {

      Entity.Builder entityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder();
      Key.Builder keyBuilder = makeKey(ancestorKey, kind, 
                                     UUID.randomUUID().toString());

      if (namespace != null) {

keyBuilder.getPartitionIdBuilder().setNamespaceId(namespace);
      }

      entityBuilder.setKey(keyBuilder.build());
      entityBuilder.getMutableProperties().put("id", 
          makeValue(id).build());
      entityBuilder.getMutableProperties().put("group", 
          makeValue(group).build());


      return entityBuilder.build();
  }

  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {


      CSVParser parser = new CSVParser();
      String[] parts = parser.parseLine(c.element());
      String id = parts[0];
      String group = parts[1];

      c.output(makeEntity(id, group));
  }
}

static Key makeAncestorKey(@Nullable String namespace, String kind) {
  Key.Builder keyBuilder = makeKey(kind, "root");
  if (namespace != null) {
      keyBuilder.getPartitionIdBuilder().setNamespaceId(namespace);
  }
  return keyBuilder.build();
}


public interface Options extends PipelineOptions {
  @Description("Path of the file to read from and store to Cloud Datastore")
  @Default.String("gs://myproject-263315.appspot.com/source/food.csv")
  String getInput();

  void setInput(String value);

  @Description("Dataset ID to read from Cloud Datastore")
  @Default.String("myproject-263315")
  String getProject();

  void setProject(String value);

  @Description("Cloud Datastore Entity Kind")
  @Default.String("FoodGroup")
  String getKind();

  void setKind(String value);

  @Description("Dataset namespace")
  @Default.String("nutrients")
  String getNamespace();

  void setNamespace(@Nullable String value);


  @Description("Number of output shards")
  @Default.Integer(0)
  int getNumShards();

  void setNumShards(int value);
}


public static void main(String args[]) {

 // PipelineOptionsFactory.register(Options.class);
  Options options = 
        PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);

  Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
  p.apply(TextIO.read().from(options.getInput()))
          .apply(ParDo.of(new 
CreateEntitiesFn(options.getNamespace(), options.getKind())))

.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(options.getProject()));

  p.run();

  }
}
```

I am using ecplise to develop code. Below is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~ Copyright (C) 2017 Google Inc.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  ~ use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
  ~ the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  ~ WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  ~ License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
  ~ the License.
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.dataflow1</groupId>
  <artifactId>my.artifact1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <bigquery.version>v2-rev374-1.23.0</bigquery.version>
    <google-clients.version>1.23.0</google-clients.version>
    <guava.version>20.0</guava.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <joda.version>2.4</joda.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.6.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <pubsub.version>v1-rev382-1.23.0</pubsub.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.20.1</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ossrh.snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype OSS Repository Hosting</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>all</parallel>
          <threadCount>4</threadCount>
          <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Ensure that the Maven jar plugin runs before the Maven
        shade plugin by listing the plugin higher within the file. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>

      <!--
        Configures `mvn package` to produce a bundled jar ("fat jar") for runners
        that require this for job submission to a cluster.
      -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>${project.artifactId}-bundled-${project.version}</finalName>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Adds a dependency on a specific version of the Dataflow SDK. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencies below this line are specific dependencies needed by the examples code. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>${google-clients.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>${bigquery.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
      <version>${google-clients.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>${pubsub.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>${joda.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      <!-- When loaded at runtime this will wire up slf4j to the JUL backend -->
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hamcrest and JUnit are required dependencies of PAssert,
         which is used in the main code of DebuggingWordCount example. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When executing the code via maven with below command,

```
mvn compile exec:java -e -Dexec.mainClass=com.dataflow1.PipelineClass -Dexec.args="--project=myproject-263315 --runner=DataflowRunner" -Pdataflow-runner
```

I am getting the bleow error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property [project] is marked with contradictory annotations. Found [[Default.String(value=myproject-263315) on my.dataflow1.PipelineClass$Options#getProject()], [Default.InstanceFactory(value=class org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$DefaultProjectFactory) on org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions#getProject()], [Default.InstanceFactory(value=class org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$DefaultProjectFactory) on org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions#getProject()]].
```

Can somebody help me in getting this corrected. Held up in this and struck up in this for long. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473024/import-csv-into-google-cloud-datastore), that maybe is useful for you. It has a Java solution and also a simple Python script. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The option "Project" is a reserved in the PiplineOptions. "JobName" is another.

Comment: What happen if the option is reserved? Is impossible to setup the value in the `PipelineOptionsFactory`? I'm trying to set up the option `region` (apache beam 2.21.0) and I get the same error: `Property [region] is marked with contradictory annotations. Found [[Default.String(value=europe-west1) on .options.IngestionOptions#getRegion()], [Default.InstanceFactory(value=class org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions$DefaultGcpRegionFactory) on org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions#getRegion()]]`